# Why is Google Drive API call from .NET Core 3.1 not authenticated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We have a .NET Core 3.1 project where we want to make calls to get Google Drive information from our Google Drive.

Using this project as a basis

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3.IntegrationTests

our project implements the following:

Created a project and obtained a client_id and secret in our Google account.

Includes the Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 and Google.Apis.Drive.v3 packages

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.78" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3" Version="1.49.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Drive.v3" Version="1.49.0.2194" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="StringTemplate4" Version="4.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then in Startup.cs has the following to integrate w/ the Google Drive API

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

 ...

  // This configures Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 for use in this app.
  services
      .AddAuthentication(o =>
      {
        // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
        // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
        // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
        o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
        // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
        o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      })
      .AddCookie()
      .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
      {
        options.ClientId = "<client_id";
        options.ClientSecret = "<secret>";
      });

 ...

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

 ...

  // Google API initialization
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();

 ...
}
```

Then a controller has the following method to make a call to the Google Drive API

```
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveReadonly)]
public async Task<List<GDFolder>> GetRoot([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
  try
  {
    GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
      HttpClientInitializer = cred
    });
    var fileListRequest = service.Files.List();
    fileListRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime)";
    fileListRequest.PageSize = 25;
    fileListRequest.Q = $"'{ROOT_ID}' in parents and mimeType='{GDMIMETypeString.FOLDER}'{QUERY_EXCLUDETRASH}";

    var gdFiles = await fileListRequest.ExecuteAsync();


    return gdFiles;

  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get list of Google Drive files", exc);
  }

}
```

When the line *GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();* is executed an exception is thrown with the following error.

*"Cannot get credential when not authenticated."*

What might be incorrect about our implementation to cause this authentication error?

Comment: You created web auth credentials correct? Is it popping up and asking for authorization?

Comment: Yes, web auth credentials were created. No prompt for auth is being displayed.

Comment: Okay thats strange.   I will try to run your code in the morning and get back to you.

Comment: Did you try to get the quick start working as a separate project? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet - just to make sure that it is possible on whatever platform you are using and that your project is set up correctly.

Comment: The quick start project works. However, we are creating an API where there won't be a user to acknowledge the access. Also, the API will be residing in an Azure App Service.

Comment: Also, most of the examples show loading a credentials file but not sure how that would work in Azure. It would be helpful it that info could be passed into an auth constructor as config variables.

Comment: There won't be a user? In that case maybe you want to be looking into [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)? As any time a program interacts with a users data, they will need to authorize it somehow, unless its within your domain and you use a service account.